# MongoDB - Update a document 30 minutes after its creation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have a social app, on a `Parse Server` (`node.js`) where users post **very frequently**! What I want, is to have every post automatically updated twice, 30 minutes after its creation and 2 hours after that.

I understand the `Agenda` library can support that, but I'm not sure if it's optimized enough for say, 10000 posts/day!

Can Agenda work for that purpose and to that scale? Do you recommend anything else?

Comment: Agenda seems to be a good fit for what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

https://github.com/Automattic/kue

The library is good for scheduling works and can save the tasks in Redis, so after restarting processes you will not lose your tasks.